# How to restore all minimized windows in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

Does anyone know how to restore all minimized windows in Windows 7 to their original positions?

I know I can right click the taskbar to cascade, stack, or display them side by side. I also know that some apps let you right click on their icon in the taskbar and restore all windows for that applications.

I want them back in their original positions and sizes before I hid them to see my desktop.

Is this just not possible? I've done web searches looking for the answer and nobody lists a way to restore ALL minimized windows to their ORIGINAL positions.

Anyone?

[Edited to add: After restoring one of the minimized windows. The normal hide/restore shortcuts only *toggle* desktop and the restored window. Not all of the minimized windows. I'm looking for a way to restore all minimized windows regardless of how many of them may have been restored individually.]

Answer (score 27):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+RightClick on the button on the taskbar, and click on "Restore all windows" or type <kbd>R</kbd>.  It "restores all windows".

***Note:*** "Restore all windows" will appear as a context menu option only if
"Taskbar and Start Menu Properties" → "Taskbar buttons" is set either to

- "Always combine, hide labels" or
- "Combine when taskbar is full " **and** windows to restore *are* combined

"Restore all windows" will **not** appear in the context menu
(replaced by "Restore" only the selected window) if
"Taskbar and Start Menu Properties" → "Taskbar buttons" is set either to

- "Never Combine" or
- "Combine when taskbar is full " **and** windows to restore *are not* combined

To open "Taskbar and Start Menu Properties":

- Right click any empty area on the taskbar and select "Properties"    
  (*hint*: "Properties" will be at or near the bottom of the menu;
  the first item under "Lock the taskbar"), or
- Right click the Windows Start Button, select "Properties",
  and, in the "Taskbar and Start Menu Properties" window that opens,
  click the "Taskbar" tab.

Comment: This is the real answer.

Comment: This is NOT the real answer: if only works for one app at a time.  If you want to restore all windows from all apps, you need to depend on thw Win-Shift-M trick.

Answer (score 12):

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> should do the trick.

Comment: This doesn't work on Windows 7.

Comment: Actually it works in my W7....

Comment: @jst Interesting. I hit Win-D, then reopened a few windows from the taskbar, but then Win-Shift-M didn't do anything. What did you do?

Comment: @CajunLuke : Actually, Win+M minimizes all windows and Win+Shift+M restores all minimized windows. Been trying and saw sometimes it dows not work as expected. Sometimes it restores only some windows, sometimes nothing at all. Try this : Open more windows, tile them, Win-M and later Win-shift-M.

Comment: @jst Thanks. I didn't know about Win-M. This seems more generally useful than Wind-D.

Comment: Works perfect. Win + D is to preserve the state of individual windows.

Comment: could you mark it as answered?

Comment: This shortcut only works if we minimize using keyboard. If we minimize using mouse it doesn't work. ;)

Comment: This doesn't work consistently for me either. Shift+(RightClick followed by R) works for me though.

Answer (score 2):

This question was asked three years ago, so it looks like the answer is:  There isn't one.

But, if you're the scripting type, it's easy to make one:

With the [WASP](https://wasp.codeplex.com/) Powershell library, and a tiny amount of Powershell script, you can make one:

```
Import-Module .\WASP.dll

Select-Window | foreach { 
        if ($_.GetIsMinimized()) { $_.Restore() } }
```

And to make it a hotkey, you could use [AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org/):

```
; Windows Key + Shift + M

#+M::
PowershellExe := "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
PowershellCommand := " -Command ""& { "
PowershellCommand .= " Import-Module ""C:\WaspDirectory\WASP.dll""; "
PowershellCommand .= " Select-Window | foreach{ "
PowershellCommand .= "     if ($_.GetIsMinimized()) { $_.Restore() } } } "" "

Run %PowershellExe% %PowershellCommand%
return
```

Comment: WASP-project was discontinued at one point, but was revived into chocolatey. Everything changed in this revival, so there is no cmdlet `Select-Window` anymore, it is called `Select-UIElement`. There is no `Restore`, but `Invoke-Window.SetWindowVisualState`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe could sound silly, but did you try Win+D?

It should Hide and Show back all Windows in their original position.

Comment: I added more detail in the original question. Win+D will not work once you open a minimized window.

Comment: Win+Shift+M only works on windows you used the Win+M command. For the windows one minimized individually you have to restore them individually.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Win+D</kbd>, <kbd>Win+Shift+M</kbd>, and `Right-Click` in taskbar and type `U`

These *all* work to restore minimized windows on Windows 7.

Comment: None of those work for my Win 10. If I want to restore all minimized windows, Win-d and Win-Shift-d work only for those windows that were minimized, not for all windows. Taskbar trick doesn't work for Win10 at all.

Answer (score 0):

For WASP 2.5.0.1 this is how I modernized @sam's original version to achieve the same:

```
PS C:\> Select-UIElement | foreach {
     if ($_.GetCurrentPropertyValue( [System.Windows.Automation.AutomationProperty]::LookupById( 30075 )) = "Minimized") {
         Invoke-Window.SetWindowVisualState -state normal -InputObject $_
}}
```

To install WASP, do a `chocolatey install wasp`. See https://chocolatey.org/packages/wasp for details.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script which will restore all minimized windows when `Win + Shift + M` is pressed

```
; ### unminimize all windows
#+M::
WinGet, WindowList, List
Loop, %WindowList%
{
    WinRestore, % "ahk_id " . WindowList%A_Index%
}
return
```

Answer (score 0):

Tidytabs groups all windows and has a customisable shortcut to restore all windows from all groups to the locations you have set.  It has a free version which is basically a trial, I use the paid version (I have no connection with them or any other marketing, I just like the program).